# adding a second 3dplot

Tags: r, rgl

I have a 3d scatterplot produced as follows:

```
library(rgl)
N <- 10000

X <- rnorm(N,0,1)
Y <- rnorm(N,0,1)

Z <- X * Y

want <- Z >0 & X>0

palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red")) 
col.table <- palette(256)
col.index <- cut(Z, 256)
plot3d(X,Y,Z, col=col.table[col.index])
grid3d(c("x", "y", "z"))
```

This works fine. Now I want to overlay another plot, so I tried this:

```
par(new=F)
plot3d(X[want],Y[want],Z[want], col="black")
```

However this fails - it just overwrites the old plot. Is there a way to overlay the new plot ?

Answer (score 4):

Although I haven't tested it, I think you should start by trying `points3d` instead of `plot3d` ...  and FYI `par(new=FALSE)` doesn't have any effect on `rgl` plots at all, only base plots.

Comment: Thanks ! That explains why `par(new=F)` didn't do anything :) . `points3d` almost works except that it doesn't **overwrite** the old points, but I think I can overcome this by manually jittering them...does that sound like the best way forward ?

Comment: that, or just leave out the old points when you first plot: `plot3d(X[-want],Y[-want],Z[-want], col=col.table[col.index[-want]])` -- I think the bounding box will expand appropriately.  Or just modify `col.index` appropriately and do it all at once ...

Comment: Yes, that's a better idea, though I think the syntax is `plot3d(X[!want],Y[!want],Z[!want]`. Problem solved. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

A very simple solution is to use the `add = TRUE` argument:

```
plot3d(X[want], Y[want], Z[want], col = 'black', add = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is using a different package but with the scatterplot3d package, you can add points using the points3d attribute:

```
library(scatterplot3d)

# main scatterplot
s3d<-scatterplot3d(x1,y1,z1,color="black",
         type="l",box=FALSE,highlight.3d=F,
         xlab="x",ylab="y",zlab="z")

# add some points 
s3d$points3d(x2,y2,z2,col="red",pch=20)  

# add a line
s3d$points3d(x3,y3,z3,col="blue",type='l')
```